# Error when creating Salesforce DX project: "Trying to copy from a source that does not exist"

Tags: salesforce, vscode-extensions

I'm encountering an error when trying to create a Salesforce DX project using the SFDX CLI. The error message I'm receiving is as follows:

```
Starting SFDX: Create Project
ERROR: Trying to copy from a source that does not exist: c:\Users\Ravirajsinh(CE)\.vscode\extensions\salesforce.salesforcedx-vscode-core-60.2.3\node_modules\@salesforce\templates\lib\templates\project\standard\ScratchDef.json
```

I've double-checked the path mentioned in the error message, and the file 'ScratchDef.json' exists in that location.

Could someone please help me troubleshoot this issue? I'm not sure why the CLI is referencing this particular file or directory during project creation, and I'm unsure how to resolve it.